# Silent Redirect of Domain/WHMCS/doc.htm to Domain/doc.htm

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, whmcs

I have `WHMCS` installed.

I have discovered that it will not run in the root www direcotry and has to be in a subdirectory `wwwroot/WHMCS/`

Is their an htacces / regexp or any other way of hiding the `WHMCS` directory when browsing?

For example:
`domain.com/WHMCS/index.php` becomes: `domain.com/index.php`

and if i click on an existing link to `domain/folder/page.php`
it will retrieve the file from `domain/whmcs/folder/ppage.php` but not show `WHMCS` in the browser bar.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

WHMCS runs perfectly well in the 'root' directory - why do you think otherwise ?

Comment: GoDaddy's system only licences WHMCS for the directory and there is no access to the WHMCS website to change the dir